# Connection to postgresql from jsp

Tags: postgresql, tomcat

I can't connected to postgres server by my jsp. I have an error:

```
root cause

java.net.SocketException: Permesso negato (connect failed) 
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) 
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
```

I connect to postgres server with phpPgAdmin and with my drupal sites?
Why I can't connect with my jsp??

I have this error in this line

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/tpinet.it", "postgres","xxxx");
```

I have jdbc driver in the correct path and  I have installed 4 drupal sites that use this database and they are online.

Why in the jsp i have this error?

Comment: "Permesso negato" = access denied

Comment: Do rule out the obvious: Do you really have a database named `tpinet.it` in Postgres?  And is your Postgres server indeed running on your local computer (where you run Tomcat)?

Comment: Yes I have a database named tpinet.it in Postgres and my Postgres server run where Tomcat run (in my local computer)

Comment: Help me please I don't have a solution